# How to get "a" tag to direct user to different pages, based on the selections of multiple dropdown boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to populate dropdown boxes based on the selection of previous drop down boxes:

```js
$('#console').on('change', function() {
  $('#model').val('selectmodel');
  $('#model').change();
})
$('#model').on('change', function() {
  $('#repair').val('selectrepair');
  $('#repair').change();
})


ps4models               = new Array("PS4 (Release Model)", "PS4 Slim", "PS4 Pro");
xboxonemodels           = new Array("Xbox One (Release Model)", "Xbox One Slim", "Xbox One Scorpio");
ps3models               = new Array("PS3 (Release Model)", "PS3 Slim", "PS3 Super Slim");
xbox360models           = new Array("Xbox 360 (Release Model)", "Xbox 360 Slim", "Xbox 360 Super Slim");
wiimodels               = new Array("Wii", "Wii U");
othermodels             = new Array("Other");

ps4repairs              = new Array("test ps4",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps4slimrepairs          = new Array("test ps4 s",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps4prorepairs           = new Array("test ps4 p",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xboxonerepairs          = new Array("test xb1",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xboxoneslimrepairs      = new Array("test xb1 s",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xboxonescorpiorepairs   = new Array("test xbox1 sc",    "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps3repairs              = new Array("test ps3",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps3slimrepairs          = new Array("test ps3 s",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps3superslimrepairs     = new Array("test ps3 ss",      "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xbox360repairs          = new Array("test xb360",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xbox360slimrepairs      = new Array("test xb360 s",     "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xbox360superslimrepairs = new Array("test xb360 ss",    "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
wiirepairs              = new Array("test wii",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
wiiurepairs             = new Array("test wiiu",        "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
otherrepairs            = new Array("test other",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");


populateSelectModel();

$(function() {

  $('#console').change(function() {
    populateSelectModel();
  });

});


function populateSelectModel() {

  console = $('#console').val();
  $('#model option[value!="selectmodel"]').remove();




  if (console == 'ps4') {
    ps4models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'xboxone') {
    xboxonemodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'ps3') {
    ps3models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'xbox360') {
    xbox360models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'wii') {
    wiimodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'other') {
    othermodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

}



populateSelectRepair();

$(function() {

  $('#model').change(function() {
    populateSelectRepair();
  });

});


function populateSelectRepair() {

  model = $('#model').val();
  $('#repair option[value!="selectrepair"]').remove();



  if (model == 'PS4 (Release Model)') {
    ps4repairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS4 Slim') {
    ps4slimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS4 Pro') {
    ps4prorepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox One (Release Model)') {
    xboxonerepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox One Slim') {
    xboxoneslimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox One Scorpio') {
    xboxonescorpiorepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS3 (Release Model)') {
    ps3repairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS3 Slim') {
    ps3slimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS3 Super Slim') {
    ps3superslimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox 360 (Release Model)') {
    xbox360repairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox 360 Slim') {
    xbox360slimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox 360 Super Slim') {
    xbox360superslimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Wii') {
    wiirepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Wii U') {
    wiiurepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Other') {
    otherrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="console">
  <option value="selectconsole">Select My Console</option>
  <option value="ps4">PS4</option>
  <option value="xboxone">Xbox One</option>
  <option value="ps3">PS3</option>
  <option value="xbox360">Xbox 360</option>
  <option value="wii">Wii and Wii U</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="model">
  <option value="selectmodel">Select My Model</option>
</select>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="repair">
  <option value="selectrepair">Select My Repair</option>
</select>
<a href="">Get My Quote</a>
```

I would like the link tag after the dropdown boxes to go to a different page, based on the selections in the second and third dropdown boxes. What would be the best way to do this?

### EDIT:

Sorry I should have mentioned I can't edit the current url structure as I don't want to mess up my inbound links. So I'm just planning to have one line of code for each combination. Obviously not optimal but as long as it works. For example

If model is "ps4 slim" and repair is "hdmi replacement", goto xxxxx .htm

If model is "ps3" and repair is "ylod", goto xxxxx .htm

Comment: Could you provide an example about what the href should look like ? I find it kinda hard to just guess it

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I need to keep the same links I have now, for SEO. So I will need to have separate line of code for each combination.

Comment: are you sending this data to `PHP`?

Comment: @2by2 Nope, there is a separate page for each repair

Comment: @Chris It still doesn't give any idea about what the URL should look like, without that show can we help you make it?

Comment: so you have a page like `ps4->ps4-slim->turns-on-and-off.html` and for others too?

Comment: I formatted you code, which should help you identify just how much unnecessary duplication there is.

Comment: @Carsten The url format would be "ps3-repair/ps3-slim/yellow-light-ylod.htm" . I must be missing something because the way I see it it doesn't really matter. I need a separate line of code for each link.

Comment: @Steve they won't be the same entries in the final code, they are just placeholders

Comment: @Carsten I can't edit the current url structure as I don't want to mess up my inbound links. So I'm just planning to have one line of code for each combination. Obviously not optimal but as long as it works. For example if model is ps4 slim and repair is hdmi replacement, goto xxxxx .htm. If model is ps3 and repair is ylod, goto xxxxx .htm

Comment: You could use objects instead of arrays, so key/value could be your option text and an url/path. Put the path as a value or as a data-uri in your options. Then use the select event to get the path and populate your href.

Comment: you need to explain the rules explicitly to get a decent answer. for example, what would the url for `Xbox 360 (Release Model) > HDMI port replacement` be? If it can be built dynamically from the select values (eg by replacing spaces with dashes and lowercasing) then its simple enough. If it cant be built dynamically then you need a map or somesort, which will grow very quickly as you add options (currently its 15 console variants x 4 repairs, giving 60 urls)

Comment: @Steve the problem is the current url structure wasn't designed with this in mind. The urls are not descriptive, and I need the options in the dropdown boxes to be descriptive. It will be around 200 links in total, which is a lot of code, but I don't see any other way of doing it while keeping the current url structure.

Comment: Im convinced there are better ways to do this, either by working out a logical mapping from values to existing urls (only you have enough info to do this) or changing your url structure and 301ing the old urls to retain inbound links, but if you really want to just write explicit javascript for each combination, then just attach to the links click event , perform your if checks, and then set window.location.

Comment: @Steve yes you are correct, 2by2's example does what you say. I don't really understand the code though. Where possible I prefer to use basic code I can actually understand lol. Would it significantly slow the website down, having 200 separate urls loaded into the array (as per Ahs N's example)?

Comment: No it wont slow the page down, it will just be a huge pain to maintain. If you dont plan on adding / changing the values often, it will work

Comment: Ok thanks for the help Steve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
otherrepairs = [
  ["www.a.com", "test other"],
  ["b.com", "HDMI port replacement"],
  ["c.com", "Turns on then turns off"],
  ["d.com", "Can't insert or eject disc"]
];

if (model == 'Other') {
    otherrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t[0]).text(t[1]));
    });
  }
```

Also update this:

```
$(".browse").click(function() {
  window.location = $("#repair").val();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/dpw3hcpq/)

The above is how I would structure the array to accommodate the links.

I applied the new structure only to the "Other" option for the sake of demo.
You will need to replicate for the rest of the code.

I added a class to the link and also to the last drop down so that I can refer to them via JQuery and redirect to the required page.

Comment: That looks promising. How would I get the "a" tag to retrieve the link from the array?

Comment: Check the JSFiddle demo, I get the links loaded as the value in the last drop down. And when the link is clicked, it reads the value of the dropdown (which is the url from the array) and redirects to it.

Comment: Just tested it on live website. The link comes back as undefined :-(

Comment: Added the JS code that uses `#repair` instead of `.last-option`. I tested on the site through the console. It works for me. Please change, test and let me know :)

Comment: @Chris you can also use `data-*` to save your urls and when select change get the url from `data-*` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: @Chris Awesome! :D

Answer (score 1):

Give your link an `id="url"` with each select change built url based on the value of the selected item

```js
$('#console').on('change', function() {
    $('#model').val('selectmodel');
    $('#url').attr('href', $(this).val() + '-repair/' + $('#model').val() + '/' + $('#repair').val() + '.html');
    $('#model').change();
})
$('#model').on('change', function() {
    $('#repair').val('selectrepair');
    $('#repair').change();
    $('#url').attr('href', $(this).val() + '-repair/' + $('#model').val() + '/' + $('#repair').val() + '.html');
})
$('#repair').on('change', function () {
    $('#url').attr('href', $(this).val() + '-repair/' + $('#model').val() + '/' + $('#repair').val() + '.html');
})


ps4models               = new Array("PS4 (Release Model)", "PS4 Slim", "PS4 Pro");
xboxonemodels           = new Array("Xbox One (Release Model)", "Xbox One Slim", "Xbox One Scorpio");
ps3models               = new Array("PS3 (Release Model)", "PS3 Slim", "PS3 Super Slim");
xbox360models           = new Array("Xbox 360 (Release Model)", "Xbox 360 Slim", "Xbox 360 Super Slim");
wiimodels               = new Array("Wii", "Wii U");
othermodels             = new Array("Other");

ps4repairs              = new Array("test ps4",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps4slimrepairs          = new Array("test ps4 s",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps4prorepairs           = new Array("test ps4 p",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xboxonerepairs          = new Array("test xb1",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xboxoneslimrepairs      = new Array("test xb1 s",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xboxonescorpiorepairs   = new Array("test xbox1 sc",    "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps3repairs              = new Array("test ps3",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps3slimrepairs          = new Array("test ps3 s",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps3superslimrepairs     = new Array("test ps3 ss",      "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xbox360repairs          = new Array("test xb360",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xbox360slimrepairs      = new Array("test xb360 s",     "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xbox360superslimrepairs = new Array("test xb360 ss",    "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
wiirepairs              = new Array("test wii",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
wiiurepairs             = new Array("test wiiu",        "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
otherrepairs            = new Array("test other",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");


populateSelectModel();

$(function() {

  $('#console').change(function() {
    populateSelectModel();
  });

});


function populateSelectModel() {

  console = $('#console').val();
  $('#model option[value!="selectmodel"]').remove();




  if (console == 'ps4') {
    ps4models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'xboxone') {
    xboxonemodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'ps3') {
    ps3models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'xbox360') {
    xbox360models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'wii') {
    wiimodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'other') {
    othermodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

}



populateSelectRepair();

$(function() {

  $('#model').change(function() {
    populateSelectRepair();
  });

});


function populateSelectRepair() {

  model = $('#model').val();
  $('#repair option[value!="selectrepair"]').remove();



  if (model == 'PS4 (Release Model)') {
    ps4repairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS4 Slim') {
    ps4slimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS4 Pro') {
    ps4prorepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox One (Release Model)') {
    xboxonerepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox One Slim') {
    xboxoneslimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox One Scorpio') {
    xboxonescorpiorepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS3 (Release Model)') {
    ps3repairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS3 Slim') {
    ps3slimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS3 Super Slim') {
    ps3superslimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox 360 (Release Model)') {
    xbox360repairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox 360 Slim') {
    xbox360slimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox 360 Super Slim') {
    xbox360superslimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Wii') {
    wiirepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Wii U') {
    wiiurepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Other') {
    otherrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="console">
  <option value="selectconsole">Select My Console</option>
  <option value="ps4">PS4</option>
  <option value="xboxone">Xbox One</option>
  <option value="ps3">PS3</option>
  <option value="xbox360">Xbox 360</option>
  <option value="wii">Wii and Wii U</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="model">
  <option value="selectmodel">Select My Model</option>
</select>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="repair">
  <option value="selectrepair">Select My Repair</option>
</select>
<a href="" id="url">Get My Quote</a>
```

The are better ways you can store the links inside an array and compare the values from all the values from select and set the correct url from there.

**UPDATE**

you can also save your `URL` partials inside [data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

> The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application.

```js
$('#console').on('change', function () {
        $('#model').val('selectmodel');
        $('#url').attr('href', $(this).find(':selected').data('url') + '/' + $('#model').find(':selected').data('url') + '/' + $('#repair').find(':selected').data('url'));
        $('#model').change();
    })
    $('#model').on('change', function () {
        $('#repair').val('selectrepair');
        $('#repair').change();
        $('#url').attr('href', $('#console').find(':selected').data('url') + '/' + $(this).find(':selected').data('url') + '/' + $('#repair').find(':selected').data('url'));
    })
    $('#repair').on('change', function () {
        $('#url').attr('href', $('#console').find(':selected').data('url') + '/' + $('#model').find(':selected').data('url') + '/' + $(this).find(':selected').data('url'));
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="console">
    <option value="selectconsole">Select My Console</option>
    <option data-url="ps4" value="ps4">PS4</option>
    <option data-url="xboxone" value="xboxone">Xbox One</option>
    <option data-url="ps3" value="ps3">PS3</option>
    <option data-url="xbox360" value="xbox360">Xbox 360</option>
    <option data-url="wii" value="wii">Wii and Wii U</option>
    <option data-url="other" value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="model">
    <option value="selectmodel">Select My Model</option>
    <option data-url="ps4-release" value="PS4 (Release Model)">PS4 (Release Model)</option>
    <option data-url="ps4-slim" value="PS4 Slim">PS4 Slim</option>
    <option data-url="ps4-pro" value="PS4 Pro">PS4 Pro</option>
</select>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="repair">
    <option value="selectrepair">Select My Repair</option>
    <option data-url="ps4-test.html" value="test ps4">test ps4</option>
    <option data-url="hdmi-replacement.html" value="HDMI port replacement">HDMI port replacement</option>
    <option data-url="turns-on-off.html" value="Turns on then turns off">Turns on then turns off</option>
    <option data-url="cant-insert-disc.html" value="Can't insert or eject disc">Can't insert or eject disc</option>
</select>
<a href="" id="url">Get My Quote</a>
```

Comment: Sorry I need each link to be individually specified. I know it will be a lot of code but I can't change the current url structure, for SEO reasons. The current url structure is not descriptive, and I need the options in the drop down boxes to be descriptive.

Comment: will storing your url inside `data` affect SEO?

Comment: Apologies 2by2, I read your post before that part was added. Would the data method be better than just storing the links in the array?

Comment: say your url will be like `ps3-repair/ps3-slim/yellow-light-ylod.htm` , you set  `ps3-repair`  in the `console`, then `ps3-slim` in the `model` and `yellow-light-ylod.htm`  in the last `select`

Comment: when you append your `<option>` add `data-url="someurl"`

Comment: Thanks 2by2, I have upvoted your answer too. To be honest I'm reluctant to change the code now I have Ahs N's example working. Will it significantly slow down the website having so many urls loaded into the array (as per Ahs N's example)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#console').on('change', function() {
  $('#model').val('selectmodel');
  $('#model').change();
})
$('#model').on('change', function() {
  $('#repair').val('selectrepair');
  $('#repair').change();
})

$('#repair').on('change',function(){
  $('#anchor').attr('href','www.demo.com/'+$('#repair').val()+'/'+$('#console').val()+'/'+$('#model').val());
});

ps4models               = new Array("PS4 (Release Model)", "PS4 Slim", "PS4 Pro");
xboxonemodels           = new Array("Xbox One (Release Model)", "Xbox One Slim", "Xbox One Scorpio");
ps3models               = new Array("PS3 (Release Model)", "PS3 Slim", "PS3 Super Slim");
xbox360models           = new Array("Xbox 360 (Release Model)", "Xbox 360 Slim", "Xbox 360 Super Slim");
wiimodels               = new Array("Wii", "Wii U");
othermodels             = new Array("Other");

ps4repairs              = new Array("test ps4",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps4slimrepairs          = new Array("test ps4 s",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps4prorepairs           = new Array("test ps4 p",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xboxonerepairs          = new Array("test xb1",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xboxoneslimrepairs      = new Array("test xb1 s",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xboxonescorpiorepairs   = new Array("test xbox1 sc",    "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps3repairs              = new Array("test ps3",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps3slimrepairs          = new Array("test ps3 s",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
ps3superslimrepairs     = new Array("test ps3 ss",      "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xbox360repairs          = new Array("test xb360",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xbox360slimrepairs      = new Array("test xb360 s",     "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
xbox360superslimrepairs = new Array("test xb360 ss",    "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
wiirepairs              = new Array("test wii",         "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
wiiurepairs             = new Array("test wiiu",        "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");
otherrepairs            = new Array("test other",       "HDMI port replacement", "Turns on then turns off", "Can't insert or eject disc");


populateSelectModel();

$(function() {

  $('#console').change(function() {
    populateSelectModel();
  });

});


function populateSelectModel() {

  console = $('#console').val();
  $('#model option[value!="selectmodel"]').remove();




  if (console == 'ps4') {
    ps4models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'xboxone') {
    xboxonemodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'ps3') {
    ps3models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'xbox360') {
    xbox360models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'wii') {
    wiimodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (console == 'other') {
    othermodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

}



populateSelectRepair();

$(function() {

  $('#model').change(function() {
    populateSelectRepair();
  });

});


function populateSelectRepair() {

  model = $('#model').val();
  $('#repair option[value!="selectrepair"]').remove();



  if (model == 'PS4 (Release Model)') {
    ps4repairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS4 Slim') {
    ps4slimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS4 Pro') {
    ps4prorepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox One (Release Model)') {
    xboxonerepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox One Slim') {
    xboxoneslimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox One Scorpio') {
    xboxonescorpiorepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS3 (Release Model)') {
    ps3repairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS3 Slim') {
    ps3slimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'PS3 Super Slim') {
    ps3superslimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox 360 (Release Model)') {
    xbox360repairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox 360 Slim') {
    xbox360slimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Xbox 360 Super Slim') {
    xbox360superslimrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Wii') {
    wiirepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Wii U') {
    wiiurepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }

  if (model == 'Other') {
    otherrepairs.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#repair').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
    });
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="console">
  <option value="selectconsole">Select My Console</option>
  <option value="ps4">PS4</option>
  <option value="xboxone">Xbox One</option>
  <option value="ps3">PS3</option>
  <option value="xbox360">Xbox 360</option>
  <option value="wii">Wii and Wii U</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="model">
  <option value="selectmodel">Select My Model</option>
</select>
<select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="repair">
  <option value="selectrepair">Select My Repair</option>
</select>
<a href="" id="anchor">Get My Quote</a>
```

Please check the code 
after change of last select box . I get the value from all other select and created a link for anchor

Thanks might help you out

Comment: Sorry I need each link to be individually specified. I know it will be a lot of code but I can't change the current url structure, for SEO reasons. The current url structure is not descriptive, and I need the options in the drop down boxes to be descriptive.